# how to extract the string between the particular symbol * in c#

Tags: c#, string

I have 3 values in a string from that i need to extract 3 values.sample string is `"AA:7.5*BB:3.8*CCCC:27"`
I need `AA`, `BB` and `CCCC` value from the string. I was using `SubString`, but the `Position` some times vary so I need to get values between first star, and first and second *, from second star.

fiddle
https://dotnetfiddle.net/g4Qdif

c# code

```
string data = "AA:7.5*BB:3.8*CCCC:27";
string value1 = data.Substring(3,3);
string value2 = data.Substring(10,3);
string value3 = data.Substring(19,2);
```

Comment: Use IndexOf to get the location of your *

Comment: If there is always going to be stars you could split on them

Comment: how to find the index of second * ?

Comment: @viion AA, BB and CCCC will always be same no of characters it will not change. actual values are PH,DO and temp which are always be static .and star also will not change.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Split` by `*` and then each section `Split` by `:` and take first:

```
var result = data.Split('*').Select(s => s.Split(':')[1]).ToList();
string ph = result[0];
string @do = result[1];
string temp = result[2];
```

Comment: im getting values like this AA
BB
CCCC. i want the values not variable names in ur first snippet.

Comment: @vinilapriya - please supply real string you are working on. For the one you gave it works